# Datatables, how to make responsive columns clickable for sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any way to make the columns affected by `responsive: true` still clickable? In this case, the `Date Added` column is no longer clickable to be sorted. It would be very great in this table that has a lot of columns to be able to sort by Date Added while still seeing some of the information without collapsing/expanding.

[image]